# How do I undo a merge , after I merged a branch into master branch

Tags: version-control, git-merge, atlassian-sourcetree

[image]

Guys I want to unmerge this localdevelopment branch from my master branch , also I pushed the master to origin/master , so now the commit history has also changed in the remote where in master branch I am also seeing the commits of this localdevelopment branch because I merged it , I only want the blue dots / commits from the above pic to be shown in the master branch , any fix for this.

Comment: Was the `git switch` command unsuccessful? It avoided having to copy a commit SHA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git log 
copy commit from there
and then

git reset --hard "your commit" 
git push -f origin master

try this :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of copying commit, you can reset your branch with [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) (Git 2.24+, Q3 2019):

```
git switch -C master master~1
git push -f
```

From [`git switch -C`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch#Documentation/git-switch.txt--Cltnew-branchgt):

> `-C <new-branch>`
> `--force-create <new-branch>`
>
> Similar to `--create` except that if `<new-branch>` already exists, it will be reset to `<start-point>`.
> This is a convenient shortcut for:
>
> ```
> $ git branch -f <new-branch>
> $ git switch <new-branch>
> ```

By resetting master to one commit older (`~1`), you affectively "forget" the merge commit.